# Does $(f(0)=g(0)$ or $f(1)=g(1))$ define a transitive relation on function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I need is to check if a relation is an equivalence or not. I can see that it is reflexive and symmetric but I'm not able to find out if it is transitive.

The relation is defined on the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and the relation is :

$\left\{ (f,g) \bigm| f(0)=g(0) \text{ or } f(1)=g(1) \right\}$

Comment: @cseav Of course, there's a lot of mathematics in computer science. However, I don't see anything in this question where a computational viewpoint would bring additional insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `R` be the binary relation you mentioned. If:

- `(f, g) ε R`,
- `(g, h) ε R`,

then either `f(0) = g(0)` or `f(1) = g(1)`.

Also either `g(0) = h(0)` or `g(1) = h(1)`.

So it could be `f(0) = g(0)` and `g(1) = h(1)`, while neither `f(0)` is equal to `h(0)` nor `f(1)` is equal to `h(1)`.

Thus `(f, h)` doesn't belong to `R`, so `R` isn't transitive.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @FrankW: Thanks! I don't know LaTeX, and wasn't aware of that introduction, I'll check it.

Comment: Oh! I got it, it is "**OR**" which is responsible!

Comment: It's a little like the human relationship of being a cousin.  It can be that A is a cousin to B and B is a cousin to C yet A and C are not related at all (any more than any two humans are).